# How to use "interface" in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am actually working on a project, which has one file like this.

```
#include "Preference.h"

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <exception>

namespace MedicalStudentMatcher
{
    class PreferenceException: public std::exception
    {
    public:
        PreferenceException(std::string message) : m_message(message) {}

        virtual ~PreferenceException() { }

        virtual const char* what() const throw()
        {
            return m_message.c_str();
        }

    private:
        std::string m_message;

    };

    class PreferenceReader
    {
    public:
        PreferenceReader(std::string filename);
        virtual ~PreferenceReader();

        std::list<Preference<std::string, std::string>> ReadPreferences();

    private:
        std::string m_filename;

        std::string trim(std::string str);
    };
}
```

Now the questions are 
1. How is the constructor working ? (Please bear in mind that I am a newbie to STL in C++ , and any kind of advanced methods in C++)
2. Explain the syntax of what() function.(Why there are two const then a char * and then a throw) 
3. What does the below line mean

```
std::list<Preference<std::string, std::string>> ReadPreferences();
```

4. I want to traverse through this list. How do I go about it.?

```
list<Preference<string, string>> hospitalPrefs = hospitalReader.ReadPreferences();
    list<Preference<string, string>> studentPrefs = studentReader.ReadPreferences();
    list<Match<string, string>> matches;
```

5. How do template class work in the following case
 and how is preference class using it. What is P m_preferrer declare ? How are "initialisation list" working in this case?

```
template <class P, class O>
    class Preference
    {
    private:
        P   m_preferrer;
        O   m_preferred;
        int m_value;

    public:
        Preference(const P& preferrer, const O& preferred, int value) : m_preferrer(preferrer), m_preferred(preferred), m_value(value) {}
        virtual ~Preference() {}

        P   getPreferrer() const { return m_preferrer; }
        O   getPreferred() const { return m_preferred; }
        int getValue()     const { return m_value; }


    };

    template <class P, class O> 
    bool less_than(const Preference<P, O>& p1, const Preference<P, O>& p2)
    {
        return p1.getValue() < p2.getValue();
    }
}
```

Even after thorough googling i couldn't find answer to these question. 
 
Please help. if you need any more info on other files, kindly comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `PreferenceException` constructor uses an "initialization list" to set `m_message`.  Now that you know that term, you can search for it to learn more.
2. `virtual const char* what() const throw()` declares "A virtual (runtime polymorphic) function which returns a pointer to (an array of) characters, where that pointer cannot be used to modify those characters."  The trailing "const throw()" mean "This function cannot modify its implicit `this` argument, i.e. it cannot modify the instance of the class on which it was called, and it cannot throw any exceptions."
3. That's a member function declaration.  The function should be defined elsewhere.  The function returns a (doubly-linked) list of Preferences.
4. Try this:

---

```
list<Preference<string, string>> hospitalPrefs = hospitalReader.ReadPreferences();
for (Preference<string, string>& pref : hospitalPrefs)
{
    // do something with pref
}
```

Or if you're stuck on C++98 instead of C++11:

```
list<Preference<string, string>> hospitalPrefs = hospitalReader.ReadPreferences();
for (list<Preference<string, string>>::iterator it = hospitalPrefs.begin(); it != hospitalPrefs.end(); ++it)
{
    // do something with pref
}
```

Comment: Just improved the 2nd question. Can you answer now? and how does doubly linked list work in this case can you shed more light on it?

Comment: @SaumyaPant: OK I added an answer for your point 2.  As for "shedding more light" on a linked list, that is again too broad and I will not answer it.  Please read about linked lists and then ask a new, separate question if needed.

Comment: I read about linked list and doubly linked list, what i cannot comprehend is how to use list<Preference<string,string> to access members of "preference" class(Say getvalue, or m_message)(Frankly i am seeing this kind of list for the first time)

Comment: In my example code, "do something with pref" means you can do `pref.getValue()` etc.